# Lerna adding command exits with the error of not related packages

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, npm, lerna

I'm using lerna to manage my multirepo with packages that are relating to each other. I did not have this issue before instalation of a new opereating system. Now when I'm trying to use `lerna add` to add a dependency on package to package, it produces error with the mentioned packages that are not related to either the one that I'm targeting and the one that is a dependency.

Here is my console output:

```
[filip@filip-thinkpad platform]$ lerna add @devell-platform/webcomponents-base --scope=@devell-platform/web-manual
lerna notice cli v3.18.3
lerna notice filter including "@devell-platform/web-manual"
lerna info filter [ '@devell-platform/web-manual' ]
lerna info Adding @devell-platform/webcomponents-base in 1 package
lerna info Bootstrapping 26 packages
lerna info Installing external dependencies
lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in '@devell-platform/model'
lerna ERR! npm install stderr:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@devell-platform%2fbase-types - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@devell-platform/base-types@0.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/filip/.npm/_logs/2020-09-27T13_19_58_840Z-debug.log

lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in '@devell-platform/model'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 3 child processes to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in '@devell-platform/model'
lerna ERR! npm install stderr:
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@devell-platform%2fbase-types - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@devell-platform/base-types@0.0.0' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/filip/.npm/_logs/2020-09-27T13_19_58_840Z-debug.log

lerna ERR! npm install exited 1 in '@devell-platform/model'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 3 child processes to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
```

The package  `@devell-platform/webcomponents-base` has no dependency on either `@devell-platform/model` nor `@devell-platform/base-types`.

I tried various things, like deleting the `model` package, but then some other package
is displayed as the cause of the error.

Answer (score 1):

There is no package `@devell-platform/webcomponents-base`. If it existed before, it must have been removed.

This has nothing to do with `lerna` but is just a coincidence. A plain install with `npm install @devell-platform/webcomponents-base` fails as well.